# How to save file to server: PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: save, phpspreadsheet

I have been using this for years and been forcing a xlsx to download to the users personal computer. I now need to modify it to save to the server but I am not having any luck...

this is my code, i added the 2 lines to the end.

I commented out all this code with no luck
"Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)"

I have tried rewriting it in many different combinations, no luck

```
// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');

header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="rep_balance-'.date("F j, Y").'.xlsx"');

// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed

header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed

header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past

header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT'); // always modified

header('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1

header('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$writer = new Xlsx($objPHPExcel);

$writer->save('php://output');


$path = '/home/paththewebsite/reps/rep_balance-'.date("F j, Y").'.xlsx';

$writer->save($path);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the lines that set the header since those are not required if you're not serving the file to the end user. And remove the "$writer->save('php://output');" line.

This should be your code

```
$writer = new Xlsx($objPHPExcel);

$path = '/home/paththewebsite/reps/rep_balance-'.date("F j, Y").'.xlsx';

$writer->save($path);
```